JavaScript await inside if statement delays code execution outside of if block
I have always thought that async/await is just a syntactical sugar around Promises and before actually executing it, JavaScript engine:

Wraps code after await into .then()
Wraps code inside catch {} block into .catch()
Wraps code inside finally {} block into .finally()

But then on the MDN article about await I have read that await

pauses the execution of its surrounding

Which is a fundamentally different thing. I came up with an example of testing that.


const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('promise resolves');
    res();
  }, 2000);
});

async function asyncFunc() {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    await promise;
    console.log('#1 this executes after a delay 50% times');
  }
  else {
    console.log('#2 this executes immediately 50% times');
  }

  console.log('this should not wait for promise to resolve but it does');
}

asyncFunc();



The code above proofs the statement that code execution actually pauses, because if we try to translate it into the "promisified" version we will have a different code, namely the console.log statement that was outside of if/else statement should be duplicated in order to replicate the async/await behavior


const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('promise resolves');
    res();
  }, 2000);
});

function promiseFunc() {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    promise.then(() => {
      console.log('#1 this executes after a delay 50% times')
      console.log('this code, that was outside of if/else either goes here')
    })
  }
  else {
    console.log('#2 this executes immediately 50% times');
    console.log('or here, based on the result of if')
  }
}
promiseFunc();



This makes me feel that Promise and async/await are either slightly different things, or the code translation is extremely counterintuitive.
UPD.
From my point of view, an intuitive translation of the async code above should look like this.


const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('promise resolves');
    res();
  }, 2000);
});

function promiseFunc() {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    promise.then(() => {
      console.log('#1 this executes after a delay 50% times')
    })
  }
  else {
    console.log('#2 this executes immediately 50% times');
  }

  console.log('this is outside of if/else block and should be executed regardless of await keyword above');
}
promiseFunc();



The question is:

If it actually does a pause, can we tell that async/await and promises are not the same?
If it actually translates to Promise version before execution, why it ignores code blocks and spreads beyond them?


The await effectively puts all the subsequent code in the function into a .then(). It goes beyond block scope.

Just because that block is executed in both paths does not mean it does not follow transformation #1 that you listed. It's just that with promises only, it can't be expressed without that block being conditionally evaluated in separate continuations because of the branching behavior.

"Syntactic sugar" is such a meaningless term. But if anything async/await is 'sugar' around generator functions, not promises. https://evertpot.com/syntactic-sugar/ . But you are correct, they are not the same.

Try not to make it overly complex.  await waits for the result of a Promise before continuing.  This is quite intuitive... you just want to wait for some function to go off and do something and return a result before you move on.  async just makes a function return a Promise, and opts-in to using await inside of it.

@Pointy but if all the code after await is put into then(), is it also copied into else? Doesn't that look strange?

@fires3as0n that's the whole point of await. It's not really a "pause", it makes it as if the function runs like a synchronous function would run.

@fires3as0n also the else doesn't matter, because the if branch has already been taken. The else might as well not be there.

The fact that async/await is a syntax sugar for working with Promises does not require there to be a lexical transformation from async/await to .then taking place anywhere. They're not the same thing. You get proper stack traces with await for instance.

@Paul yes that's an important point. It's handy to think about await transforming code into .then(), but it's not really exactly like that. It's more like how generator functions work, but even then it's better to just "trust the Force" and code with await as if it imposed a "pause" semantically.

@Pointy if it is not a pause, it should be translated to Promise version before execution, and the working translation looks like a different code, this is what confusing. Also you first say that "It's not really a "pause"" and then immediately "code with await as if it imposed a "pause" semantically". - so is it a pause and not after all?

@fires3as0n again, it's more like how generators work. The await is like a yield under the covers. So it's kind-of like a .then(), but not exactly. Really, like I said, the best thing to do is to believe that it works, and once you get used to it you can dig into the details.


If it actually does a pause, can we tell that async/await and promises are not the same?

No, you can't really tell the difference. The translation indeed looks more like in your second code snippet, though of course the compiler doesn't care whether it duplicates the code (or actually just references the same code twice). Notice that even as a programmer you don't have to duplicate code for conditional promise flows.

If it actually translates to Promise version before execution, why it ignores code blocks and spreads beyond them?

It doesn't ignore all code blocks. It translates them.
The full quote from MDN is actually "… pauses the execution of its surrounding async function". It doesn't pause the execution of the if block only.
Yes, translating control structures from await to .then() code is not immediately intuitive - in particular when it comes to loops or try/catch. But that's the entire point of async/await syntax - you don't have to write these complex .then() chains any longer, and you don't need to translate anything or even think about translating it - you just use the ordinary control flow structures in asynchronous code that you're used to from synchronous code.
Whether the compiler does a complicated translation under the hood, or uses a different and more efficient execution model, doesn't matter and is not really observable.

Interesting. So, we can say, that JS engine indeed does the translation, and does it in such a way, that when executing the resulting code, it should behave like if the whole original async function execution was paused until promise is fulfilled. Which indeed can lead to code duplication shown in example 2. (where code duplication is spoken in terms of execution flow, not how engine works or does that internally)

Yes. "It should behave like if the whole original async function execution was paused until promise is fulfilled" is the whole point. It doesn't matter to the JavaScript programmer how it does that - and in fact, details change often when new optimisations are implemented.

@Bergi Thanks for the answer, I still think that understanding how tools, that you use, work internally does matter a lot for a good engineer.

@fires3as0n Sure, but you can't expect their internal workings to be intuitive :-) Also not all environments are the same, and you haven't asked about a concrete tool. Babel does it very different (with an actual source transformation) than a modern JS engine, which is indeed able to suspend a function mid-execution and then resume it later, very similar to how yield works in generator functions. This is much more efficient than doing source transforms and constructing huge numbers of complicated closures.
